# How to make a C program run faster?

Tags: c

I have to calculate the number of prime numbers in the interval from 0 to N. The problem is that the program runs very slowly when N > 100000.

```
int main(){

long int  i, j, n,isPrime;
long int N, count;

N = 10000000;



count = 0;
for(i = 2; i <= N; i++){
    isPrime = 0;

    for(j = 2; j <= i/2; j++){

         if(i % j == 0){
            isPrime = 1;

             break;
         }
    }
     if(isPrime==0 && N!= 1)


     /*printf("%d ",i);*/
     if(isPrime==0 && N!= 1)
    count++;

}

    printf(" %li ", count);     
   getch();
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: We are not a code-review site.

Comment: Start with considering an algorithm such as [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).  It will provide you with some insights on what makes algorithms more or less efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't have to go up to `i/2` to look for the prime, just look up to the square root. Any divisors greater that the square root aren't useful: you'd have already found their counterpart before.

```
int sqr = int(sqrt(i));  // make sure it is computed only once
for(j = 2; j <= sqr; j++){
```

that should do it...

or (as suggested) compare squares to avoid computing sqrt at all

```
for(j = 2; j*j <= i; j++){
```

That method is good to find if a big number is prime. But to find a range of prime numbers, you'd be better off with a [Sieve of Erathostenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891524/sieve-of-erastothenes) algorithm  (I have linked the C version).

Comment: `j*j <= i` is a faster calculation than `j <= int(sqrt(i))`.  But fixing the algorithm is a better starting point than tweaking this implementation.

Comment: that's soo true. Editing.

Comment: I'd save the sqrt() result before the loop, and check against that in the loop.

Comment: @donjuedo I have thought of that too. but the optimizer could probably take care of that

Comment: "Might" is the operative word there.  The multiplication is not free, and j changes all the time.  Despite these, I think your answer is a good one.

Comment: yes, it would have to be benched, and would probably depend on the CPU you're running it on.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, this line:

```
for(i = 2; i <= N; i++){
```

Starts at `i=2`, then goes to:

```
i=3
i=4
i=5
i=6
i=7
```

Why are you checking values like 4, 6, and 8?
You can skip those immediately!

Change your line to:

```
for(i = 3; i <= N; i+=2){   /* Start at 3, then 5, 7, 9, 11, etc. */
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the modulus operation. Use the sieve.

```
static unsigned char sieve[10000000] = {0};

long countprimes(long N)
{
    long answer = 0;
    long i;
    long j = 2;
    long rootN = ceil(sqrt(N)); 
    while(j < rootN)
    {
       for(i=j+j;i<N;i+=j)
          sieve[i] = 1;
        j++;
        while(sieve[j])
           j++;

    }
    for(i=2;i<N;i++)
       if(!sieve[i])
          answer++;
    return answer;
}
```